# Can't find where context is missing

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception

I've been refactoring a previous project to use fragments instead of creating separate activities as a school assignment. I've been trying to find out where this error is for close to an hour now and no luck. I get context missing when I add this line `canvas.setColor(color, position);`

Here's the Main activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PaletteFragment.SpinnerSelectedInterface {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            PaletteFragment palette = PaletteFragment.newInstance();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putStringArray(KeyData.PASS_COLOR, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors));
            bundle.putStringArray(KeyData.PASS_POSITION, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorNames));
            palette.setArguments(bundle);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.palette_fragment, palette).commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void setCanvasColor(String color, int position) {
            CanvasFragment canvas = CanvasFragment.newInstance(null);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.canvas_fragment, canvas).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            canvas.setColor(color, position);
        }
    }
```

And here's the fragment:

```
public class CanvasFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView displayColor;
    private View background;

    public CanvasFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static CanvasFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle) {
        CanvasFragment fragment = new CanvasFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_canvas, container, false);
        displayColor = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.displayColor);
        background = (View) v.findViewById(R.id.canvas_fragment);
        return v;
    }

    public void setColor(String color, int position){
        String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorNames);
        displayColor.setText(names[position]);
        background.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    }
```

I've tried override onAttach and onDetach on the canvas fragment and adding a message listener, but still get the error as well. Would appreciate anything that could steer me in the right direction.

**Error**

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment CanvasFragment{69925d5 (240edefb-318c-4983-bd15-cf45142e849a) id=0x7f080047} not attached to a context.`

Comment: What do you mean with context missing?

Comment: Sorry not the best with terms. Here's the error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment CanvasFragment{69925d5 (240edefb-318c-4983-bd15-cf45142e849a) id=0x7f080047} not attached to a context.

Comment: when you call newInstance() method, did you try to put your activity bundle instead of null as argument?

Comment: Same error. I originally had no newInstance() variables required. I added that since the source code the professor wrote in class required bundles. Removing canvas.setColor(color, position) doesn't generate the error.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.canvas_fragment, canvas)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

You're using `commit()`. As per [its Javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#commit()):

> Schedules a commit of this transaction. **The commit does not happen immediately;** it will be scheduled as work on the main thread to be done the next time that thread is ready.

So when you immediately call `canvas.setColor(color, position)` directly afterwards, the Fragment is not attached and it doesn't yet have a `Context` associated with it.

If you want the Fragment to be immediately added, you want to use [commitNow()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#commitNow()), which forces the transaction to happen immediately. This ensures that it'll be done before your `setColor` method is called:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.canvas_fragment, canvas)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commitNow();
```